How to make gradle build custom non java project for android when src dir change
I want to make an android library for my own project using gradle that compiles some typescript files into JS and add it to android assets folder.
I don't want gradle to do any java thing.
How do I tell gradle to build whenever a file changes under the src dir ?
plugins {
    id "com.android.library"
}

// a wrapper closure around executing a string
// can take either a string or a list of strings (for arguments with spaces)
// prints all output, complains and halts on error


def runCommand = { strList ->
    if(strList instanceof GString) strList = strList.toString()
    assert (strList instanceof String ||
            (strList instanceof List && strList.each { it instanceof String })    \
    )
    def proc = strList.execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.out.close()
    proc.waitFor()

    print "[INFO] ( "
    if (strList instanceof List) {
        strList.each { print "${it} " }
    } else {
        print strList
    }
    println " )"

    if (proc.exitValue()) {
        println "gave the following error: "
        println "[ERROR] ${proc.getErrorStream()}"
    }
    assert !proc.exitValue()
}

def src = new File(projectDir, "src").absolutePath
def build = new File(projectDir, "output").absolutePath

tasks.register('buildWeb') {
    mustRunAfter tasks.build
    group "Build"
    description "Builds the web side of Sharing app"
    doFirst {
        runCommand "npm run build --prefix $src"
    }
}



android {
    compileSdk 34
    namespace "src"
    sourceSets {
        main.assets.srcDirs += build
    }
}




Continuous Builds allows you to automatically re-execute the requested tasks when file inputs change.
You will need to ensure your custom tasks declares its inputs and outputs for continuous builds to work. See tasks inputs and outs for more details.
Finally, you can take advantage of the Exec task type rather than the generic one you have for buildWeb. There is also a Gradle plugin you can apply for Node: Gradle Plugin for Node
